# SQL Precedence Query

Tags: sql, operator-precedence

I have a logging table which has three columns.  One column is a unique identifier, One Column is called "Name" and the other is "Status".
Values in the Name column can repeat so that you might see Name "Joe" in multiple rows.  Name "Joe" might have a row with a status "open", another row with a status "closed", another with "waiting" and maybe one for "hold". I would like to, using a defined precedence in this highest to lowest order:("Closed","Hold","Waiting" and "Open") pull the highest ranking row for each Name and ignore the others.  Anyone know a simple way to do this?

BTW, not every Name will have all status representations, so "Joe" might only have a row for "waiting" and "hold", or maybe just "waiting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a second table named something like "Status_Precedence", with rows like:

```
Status  | Order
---------------
Closed  |  1
Hold    |  2
Waiting |  3
Open    |  4
```

In your query of the other table, do a join to this table (on `Status_Precedence.Status`) and then you can `ORDER BY Status_Precedence.Order`.

Comment: I agree that this will essentially sort my names and status, but how then do I only keep the row with the highest number for each name?

Comment: SELECT Status from Table,Order from Status_Precedence where Table.Status = Status_Precedence.Status ORDER BY Status_Precedence ORDER DESC;

Comment: "SELECT Status from Table,Order from Status_Precedence where"?  Am I missing something?

Comment: ... WHERE `Table`.`Status` = `Status_Precedence`.`Status` ORDER BY `Status_Precedence`.`Order` DESC LIMIT 0,1; "Table" is your table -- I couldn't see the name anywhere.

Comment: I just don't get "Select Status from Table" followed by a comma?

Comment: Oh. Hum. Don't know why I did that. Late at night.
SELECT Table.Status, Status_Precedence.Order FROM Table, Status_Precedence ....

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to create another table, you can assign numeric precedence using a SELECT CASE

```
Select Name, Status, Case Status 
        When 'Closed' then 1
        When 'Hold' then 2
        When 'Waiting' then 3
        When 'Open' Then 4
        END
         as StatusID

         From Logging
Order By StatusId -- Order based on Case
```

A lookup table is also a good solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using matt b's solution and using this final query to filter out the lower ranked (lower bing higher numbered).

```
SELECT * from [TABLE] tb
LEFT JOIN Status_Precedence sp ON tb.Status = sp.Status
WHERE  sp.Rank = (SELECT MIN(sp2.rank)
                FROM[Table] tb2
           LEFT JOIN Status_Precedence sp2 ON tb2.Status = sp2.Status
                WHERE tb.Status = tb2.Status)
order by tb.[name]
```